# Torus in libgdx without object

Tags: libgdx

How do you create a torus in `libgdx` ? `Modelbuilder` doesn't support it.
I have to create a torus in code, and cant load any objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With libGDX to create custom `Model`s you'd use the `MeshBuilder`.

Via the `MeshBuilder.vertex(...)` method you can add a vertex with the necessary information, one by one. Basically you'll need two nested loops and look up the necessary formulas for the torus [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry).

You have to wrap it in `MeshBuilder.begin(...)` and `MeshBuilder.end()`.

`MeshBuilder.end()` will return a `Mesh`, which you can then pass to `ModelBuilder.fromMesh(mesh)` to get the `Model` you need.

Answer (score 1):

Find resolution, how create `torus` in `libgdx`. May will be helpfull.

```
private void createTorus (int glMaterial, float X, float Y, float Z, float widthR, 
                          float height, int divisionsU, int divisionsV, float r, float g, float b, float a) {

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.begin();
    MeshPartBuilder builder = modelBuilder.part("torus", glMaterial, Usage.Position |
            Usage.Normal, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(r, g, b, a)));
    builder.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    VertexInfo curr1 = vertTmp3.set(null, null, null, null);
    curr1.hasUV = curr1.hasPosition = curr1.hasNormal = true;
    VertexInfo curr2 = vertTmp4.set(null, null, null, null);
    curr2.hasUV = curr2.hasPosition = curr2.hasNormal = true;
    short i1, i2, i3 = 0, i4 = 0;

    int i, j, k;
    double s, t, twopi;
    twopi = 2 * Math.PI;

    for (i = 0; i < divisionsV; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= divisionsU; j++) {
            for (k = 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                s = (i + k) % divisionsV + 0.5;
                t = j % divisionsU;

                curr1.position.set(
                        (float) ((widthR+height*Math.cos(s * twopi / divisionsV))*Math.cos(t * twopi / divisionsU)),
                        (float) ((widthR+height*Math.cos(s*twopi/divisionsV))*Math.sin(t * twopi / divisionsU)),
                        (float) (height * Math.sin(s * twopi / divisionsV)));
                curr1.normal.set(curr1.position).nor();
                k--;
                s = (i + k) % divisionsV + 0.5;
                curr2.position.set(
                        (float) ((widthR+height*Math.cos(s * twopi / divisionsV))*Math.cos(t * twopi / divisionsU)),
                        (float) ((widthR+height*Math.cos(s*twopi/divisionsV))*Math.sin(t * twopi / divisionsU)),
                        (float) (height * Math.sin(s * twopi / divisionsV)));
                curr2.normal.set(curr1.normal);
                //curr2.uv.set((float) s, 0);
                i1 = builder.vertex(curr1);
                i2 = builder.vertex(curr2);
                builder.rect(i4, i2, i1, i3);
                i4 = i2;
                i3 = i1;
            }
        }
    }

    torus_Model = modelBuilder.end();
    torus_Instances = new  ModelInstance(torus_Model);
}
```